# Trim unwanted characters from the end of the last element in an array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I modify the last element in an array?

The array looks like this:

```
$fields = array("firstName = 'Bob', ",
                "lastName = 'Smith', ",
                "email = 'bob@example.com', ",
                "address = '123 anystreet', ");
```

The array is generated by a script which creates the values and adds the comma/space at the end of each string. I want to remove that comma/space from only the last element in that array. Keep in mind that the values could in fact contain a comma/space combination so only the last element and the last two characters of the last element need to be removed.

I've looked at the `end()` function but I don't think that is going to help since it just gets the value.

**Edit** Ok so I created this function/array so that I would only have one mysql function to update users. Sort of like a detect changes function and it only passes back the required/changed fields. I didn't realize there were problems associated with this approach. I thought that since I already had the mysql queries written in my old functions there shouldn't be an issue with this way. The file that it's in will not be accessible to the public. I'm going to use the best answer that works for me but I'm going to search for why this is problematic and I would appreciate comments/links as to what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: This looks like SQL injection waiting to happen

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string in the generation of this array and sanitizing all the data beforehand, thanks for the concern.

Comment: Still. Why not use key/value pairs natively? Storing full SQL expressions just causes problems, like the one you're experiencing now.

Comment: If it is for a database you should go for a prepared statement with bound variables.

Comment: The function I built takes 2 user objects and checks to see if there are any changes. The result is this array. I did this to reduce the amount of mysql functions from 10's to 1. In my mysql file I still have to hard code the SQL?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).  The input data should be better prepared prior to this stage.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Like this!

```
end($array);
$key = key($array);
reset($array);
```

Comment: If the array is an ordinary numeric one, the answer by Chris is a better one IMO. If the array is an associative one, only this one will work.

Comment: "Will this also work if the array is associative? I should have posted it that way instead :s"

Comment: It depends on what you want to modify -- The key or the value. Use `$array[$key]` to modify the value, and just `$key` to modify the key (but you already knew that)

Answer (score 16):

There's a shorthand way to do this, but it's easier to follow if it's broken out into pieces:

```
$index = count( $fields ) - 1;
$value = $fields[$index];
$fields[$index] = preg_replace( "/,\ $/", "", $value );
```

Comment: Nice. Would even be better if you just used `rtrim($value, ' ,');` instead of a regex.

Comment: or just remove the last two characters with a `substr`ing.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Or the OP could generate an array and implode with `, ` and the whole issue would disappear.

Comment: @Jan -- What if it isn't always the same length? What if there's no space on the end?

Comment: @DavidHarris you don't need to know the length in advance. Knowing the space is there does help - I think it can be expected here.

Comment: Sure you do. `,-----` vs `, ` gives a very much different result :) (Not that there ever should be, but stranger things have happened) (I use hyphens because extra spaces were trimmed). And `,` vs `, ` will just break it.

Comment: This only works if you have numerical arrays. Fails with associated arrays.

Comment: Yeah, well, the input in the question was a numerically indexed array.

Answer (score 6):

To change the value of the last numeric element:

```
$lastValue = array_pop($fields);
$fields[] = rtrim(', ',$lastValue);
```

If you are preparing these values for a query I would suggest storing everything without commas in an array then calling implode on that array when needed to prevent trailing comma problems

Answer (score 6):

Array pop and push are the easiest way to do it for basic arrays. (I know that isn't technically the question but many people will come here looking for the answer in relation to simple arrays as well).

```
<?php

function update_last(&$array, $value){
    array_pop($array);
    array_push($array, $value);     
}

?>
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
<?php

$array = [1,2,3];

update_last($array, 4); //$array = [1,2,4];

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways:

1) For associative arrays, if you don't know the last element key, you better find the last element key first and change its value.

```
$array[end((array_keys($array)))] .= ' additional text';
```

2) if you don't know and don't care about keys, you can cut the last element and create a new one.

```
$array[] = array_pop($array).' additional text';
```

Answer (score 3):

The last element of an array can always be retrieved using [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), no matter how the array is indexed. It will also remove that element from the array, which is very useful if we want to modify and then add it again, as you cannot modify the element in-place.

What you are trying to do can be done with a simple, single line of code:

```
$fields[] = preg_replace("/, $/", "", array_pop($fields));
```

That's it. Here's what it does:

- [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) searches for a [Regex pattern](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/05/29/regular-expressions-for-beginners-how-to-get-started-discovering-sensitive-data/) in a string and if found, replaces the match with an alternative string.
- The pattern we search for is `/, $/`, which means: Match for ", " (comma + space) but only if it is at the very end of the string (`$`).
- The replacement string is simply an empty string (`""`), thus the match is just deleted from the string.
- The string we want to perform that replacement on is `array_pop($fields)`, the last element of the array `$fields`, which is also removed from that array.
- The modified string is then re-added to the array at the end (`$fields[] =`  adds an element to an array without an explicit key and makes it the new last element).

Let's test it:

```
$fields = array(
    "firstName = 'Bob', ",
    "lastName = 'Smith', ",
    "email = 'bob@example.com', ",
    "address = '123 anystreet', ");

print "Before:\n\n";
print_r($fields);

$fields[] = preg_replace("/, $/", "", array_pop($fields));

print "\nAfter:\n\n";
print_r($fields);
```

Output:

```
Before:

Array
(
    [0] => firstName = 'Bob', 
    [1] => lastName = 'Smith', 
    [2] => email = 'bob@example.com', 
    [3] => address = '123 anystreet', 
)

After:

Array
(
    [0] => firstName = 'Bob', 
    [1] => lastName = 'Smith', 
    [2] => email = 'bob@example.com', 
    [3] => address = '123 anystreet'
)
```

Note how the last comma is gone? Just [try it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a180fef146fb5c5f59d4437cae8837b4021dc7c).

Answer (score 0):

stumbled upon this today. i think the easiest non-pointer-breaking way would be:

```
array_splice($array, -1, 1, strtolower(end(array_values($array))).'blah' );
```

of course you can drop array_values if you dont have to care for the pointer.
but i wonder if this is a good way, since the extract-n-replace-stuff of splice could be more demanding than a pop or sth?

Comment: I think array_pop is simpler than array_splice for this case.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7 >= 7.3.0

```
$array[array_key_last($array)] = 'new value';
```

[Demo](https://replit.com/@kirilldevope/arraykeylast#index.php)

```
$fields = array(
    "firstName = 'Bob', ",
    "lastName = 'Smith', ",
    "email = 'bob@example.com', ",
    "address = '123 anystreet', "
);

$last = $fields[array_key_last($fields)];
$last = preg_replace( "/, $/", "", $last);
$fields[array_key_last($fields)] = $last;
```

Comment: While `array_key_last()` is a highly valuable and modern piece of the puzzle, this answer does not provide the desired output expressed in the question.

Comment: @mickmackusa, isn't the accepted answer devoid of this shortcoming?

Comment: Should it be okay to not deliver the expected result if another answer does not deliver the expected result?  If someone else jumps off a bridge, do you jump off the bridge too, or do you make your own decision about what is right/wrong?  I was going to upvote your answer, but found it to be incomplete.  Now that you are arguing and not editing, I've lost the impulse.  I also don't upvote unexplained answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa this is not the main reason. I decided to submit more general answer for this kind of task because it's more valuable since the current title of the question is "Modify the last element in the array".

Comment: ...but you are not modifying the last element.  If you don't want to answer the question posted on this page, remove this half-answer and post it on a page where it is better suited -- just make sure your advice doesn't already exist there.  All posted answers must resolve the posted question.  If you don't like this question's title, suggest an edit.

Comment: Should I delete my answer? Or I can improve it somehow?

Comment: You can always choose to [edit] your answer so that it resolves the question.  If you don't know how to resolve the asked question, you should remove your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think PHP's [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function might be a good alternative, instead of generating the commas yourself.

Barring that, you would have to use something like:

```
$lastfield = $fields[count($fields)-1];
$lastfield = str_split($lastfield,strlen($lastfield)-2);
$fields[count($fields)-1] = $lastfield;
```

The first and third lines are included to make the second line easier to read, but this could easily be compounded to one line.

Comment: This only works if you have numerical arrays. Fails with associated arrays.